# How to do Histogram Equalization based on audio frequency?

Tags: python, python-3.x, signal-processing

I have already tried histogram equalization based on image and it works just fine.
[image: image histogram equalization]

But now I want to implement the same approach using audio frequency instead of image gray scale. Which means I would like to make the spectrum flatter. The sampling rate I use is 44.1kHz and want to make the frequency evenly spread to range 0-22050Hz, but the peak is still the highest.

Here is the spectrum:
[image]

And this is what I have tried:
[image]

I think the original histogram I plot is already wrong, I can't count the number of occurrences per frequency, or maybe I shouldn't do this at all. Somebody told me I need to use fft() but I have no idea how to do it.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Here is the code for how I plot the spectrum :

```
import librosa
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

file = 'example.wav'
y, sr = librosa.load(file, sr=None)

n_fft = 2048
S = librosa.stft(y, n_fft=n_fft, hop_length=n_fft//2)

S = abs(S)
D_AVG = np.mean(S, axis=1)

plt.figure(figsize=(25, 12))

plt.bar(np.arange(D_AVG.shape[0]), D_AVG)
x_ticks_positions = [n for n in range(0, n_fft // 2, n_fft // 16)]
x_ticks_labels = [str(sr / 2048 * n) + 'Hz' for n in x_ticks_positions]
plt.xticks(x_ticks_positions, x_ticks_labels)
plt.xlabel('Frequency')
plt.ylabel('dB')
plt.savefig('spectrum.png')
```

Comment: You're tagging this Python but you don't provide code. You also don't specify how you went from the audio to the spectrum image and to the histogram image. Furthermore, usually when people speak of equalizing a spectrum they talk about amplifying and suppressing frequencies, not moving frequencies around (changing gray values) like how image equalization works. Please clarify (along with an example) what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Mark Jeronimus , I'm sorry since this is my first question. I have added the code for how I draw the spectrum, and you can just ignore the histogram image. I just want to equalizing a spectrum which is like you said, but I don't konw how to write the code.

Answer (score 2):

"Equalization" in the sense of making a flat frequency spectrum is usually done by a [whitening transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitening_transformation). [This post on dsp.stackexchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/630/how-to-whiten-a-time-domain-signal) might also be helpful. As Mark mentioned, this spectral equalization is different from histogram equalization in image processing.

Equalizing/whitening the spectrum of a signal:

1. **Estimate the PSD.** Given an array of samples `x` with sample rate `fs`, you can compute a robust estimate of the power spectral density (PSD) with [scipy.signal.welch](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html):

   ```
   f, psd = scipy.signal.welch(x, fs=fs)
   ```

   This function performs [Welch's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_method). Basically, it divides up the signal into several segments, does FFT on each one, and averages the power spectra to get a good estimate of how much power `x` has at each frequency on average. The point of all this is it gets a more reliable frequency characterization than just taking one FFT of `x` as a whole.
2. **Compute equalizer gain.** Use `eq_gain = 1 / (1e-6 + psd)**0.5`, or something similar, to determine the gain of the equalizer. The `1e-6` denominator offset is to avoid division by zero. It often happens that the PSD extremely small for some frequencies because, say, `x` went through an anti-aliasing filter that made some high frequency powers nearly zero.
3. **Apply the equalizer gain.** Finally, `eq_gain` needs to be applied to the signal `x` to equalize it. There are many ways this could be done, but one way is to use [scipy.signal.firwin2](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.firwin2.html) to turn the gains into an FIR filter,

   ```
   eq_filter = scipy.signal.firwin2(99, f, eq_gain, fs=fs)
   ```

   and use a convolution or [scipy.signal.lfilter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html) to apply the filter to `x`. You can then use `scipy.signal.welch` again to check that the PSD is flatter than before.

Comment: Should I use `scipy.signal.butter` before applying the eq_filter to `x`? I tried both `scipy.signal.lfilter` and `scipy.signal.filtfilt` to apply the filter to `x` but it doesn't work, the PSD is still the same as original PSD. Could you show me the complete code in step 3 ? That would be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: In what I suggested, `scipy.signal.firwin2` designs the equalization filter; no need to use `scipy.signal.butter`. Apply the filter by convolving `eq_filter` and `x`. One way to that is `x_equalized = scipy.signal.lfilter(eq_filter, 1, x)`.