# Split mid-side channels in stereo audio file

Tags: python, audio-processing

I'd like to create a mid-side EQ in python (allows you to edit the mid and side channels separately). Any idea of how to extract the mid and side channels from an audio file?

Comment: I'm not an audio expert, so not sure what you mean manipulating a multi-channel audio file (e.g. 6 channels .wav file, etc) or manipulating frequencies on standard mono or stereo audio files. Having a quick look this looks like a step in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65229296/how-to-do-histogram-equalization-based-on-audio-frequency. Hopefully librosa can handle multiple audio channels as well, otherwise I remember [using pyaudio/numpy in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30293137/pyaudio-mixing-multiple-tracks-and-channels). (librosa/numpy might suffice)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function I found in: https://github.com/sergree/matchering/

```
import wave
import numpy as np


def lr_to_ms(array: np.ndarray) -> (np.ndarray, np.ndarray):
    array = np.copy(array)
    array[:, 0] += array[:, 1]
    array[:, 0] *= 0.5
    mid = np.copy(array[:, 0])
    array[:, 0] -= array[:, 1]
    side = np.copy(array[:, 0])
    return mid, side



wav_obj = wave.open('sound.wav', 'rb')
sampFreq = wav_obj.getframerate()
data = wav_obj.readframes(-1)
stereo_signal = np.frombuffer(data, np.int16)
stereo_signal.shape = -1, 2
left_signal, right_signal = stereo_signal[0], stereo_signal[1]
mid_signal, side_signal = lr_to_ms(np.array(stereo_signal, dtype=float))
```

The resulting mid and side signals are cast as float, you will need to change the datatype back to int16